# Possible to make webpage URL the same as an iFrame URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So I have an iFrame which I am using to load the other pages for my website. To make the website seem like it has no load time and very smooth I have made a main page, with an iFrame in the middle to load the actual pages of the website that contain all the information. I have buttons using JS to change the SRC of the iFrame so that it acts like a normal nav bar.
I am curious to know if it is possible to make the URL on the browser, the same as the URL in the iFrame. Because right now when a user is on the website, they aren't switching to different pages, meaning they can't go back or forward in history because they never left the page in the first place. This can be troubling to most users if they want to link their friends to something, or just go back a bit.

Is there a way to do this in jQuery or JavaScript? Or even better, purely in HTML or CSS?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After googling a bit of what charlietfl has said, I am now wondering if it is possible to save a website into states, which I can then give web URLs to? I just skimmed through a few pages without reading them thoroughly so I'm not exactly sure what it was talking about when it mentioned states, but maybe there is something else out there that is capable?

Comment: This is a really bad way to create a single page application both from a logistics and SEO perspective. There are much cleaner ways using ajax and history api and there are numerous frameworks you can use to simplify it all as well

Comment: You *can* check out the **history API** http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/312/history#t=201611121903357888986 but I fear you are waving your seo foot in front of google's shotgun here with the embedded **iframe**

Comment: To help with SEO I am able to just type in lots of invisible text that references to my site right? Because that's how google works? It reads all the data and paragraph text on the site to help users find exactly what their looking for? Please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try url hash like the gmail uses `#inbox` . It has the same functionality as you wish. It serves you the browser back and forward actions. You have to add more Javascript to handle those hashes. But i am not sure about its effect on seo (if you are only concerning about it).

For more details please go through these links

[Gmail like URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606640/gmail-like-url-scheme)

[Browser History Manager](https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/)